# Connect a LAN cable to LAN1 & LAN2

Tags: router, lan, layer1, cable, loop

I connected a LAN cable from the LAN-1 port to the LAN-2 port owned by the same router.

Then really weird things happened:

1. For 10 - 15 seconds, nothing happened, none of the lights on the
   modem are changed.
2. Lights on the router went crazy, they blink really fast.
3. All computers connected to that router are disconnected.
4. I have to restart the router, or my devices won't connect to it.

My question is, what happened? What are the technical details?

Comment: This sounds like a home networking question which is off-topic here. Try asking on Superuser and providing more details, such as the model of your router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't actually connect two router ports, you connected two switch ports. The router has a switch module.

You created a layer-2 broadcast storm. Broadcast is an essential part of ethernet. When a broadcast comes into a switch port, a switch must send it to all the other ports. When you connected the two switch ports, it created a loop where the broadcast was both going out all the other ports, and coming back into the switch, causing it to need to be sent out all the other ports, and causing it to come back into the switch, forever.

This caused the switch module to be completely swamped to the point that other traffic would be dropped or slowed so much that the switch module couldn't be used.

Ethernet headers don't have a TTL field like IP headers do, so there is no way to have the protocol itself break the loop. Layer-3 routing loops can happen, but they are somewhat self-limiting because of the TTL field, but they still cause major disruptions, too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally moving cable from one LAN port to another should not cause a real issue. However there is a possibility that you have created a layer 2 loop which can result in end hosts isolation. What of a router you are using? Can you please share with us the configuration of the router? It will be great if you share topology in addition to that so we can analyze the full picture.